# Will airflow pick up dynamically generated schedule interval?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I've been running airflow 1.9.0 and using dynamically generated schedule intervals.

Simply put, I take a US/Eastern timestamp from some config file, get the current system timezone (can be either EDT or EST), and convert it to UTC time then to a cron expression.

For example, if I launch the dag today (2018-07-23, EDT) and my input is 6AM US/Eastern, it will result in a dag whose schedule interval is 10AM UTC or `0 10 * * 1-5`.

My question is:
if I leave the dag running on a daily basis, will its schedule automatically update to `0 11 * * 1-5` in November, when daylight savings ends?

I specifically want to avoid using tz-aware datetimes in scheduling these dags, that's why I came up with this hacky way of timestamp conversion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What library or code are you using to do the conversion between your Eastern timestamp and generate the cron expression?  I think answering this part of your question is dependent on that information.

Anyway, this idea kind of sounds like a code smell to me.  While it would technically work, assuming you library supports that use case correctly and that the timezone library is kept up-to-date, I believe you're better off going with the standard route of determining the crontab schedule you want upfront and using that consistently.

It's also a best practice to not use local time zone, for example, in the case where you move your server from Eastern to Pacific or operate multiple servers in different timezones — using UTC everywhere keeps it simple as you scale up.

Since UTC does not have daylight saving time, this will help you avoid things like DST bugs that you'd otherwise have to address if not using UTC.

Additionally, the official Airflow docs recommend against using naive datetimes:

> Because Airflow uses time-zone-aware datetime objects. If your code creates datetime objects they need to be aware too.
>
> ...
>
> Although Airflow operates fully time zone aware, it still accepts naive date time objects for start_dates and end_dates in your DAG definitions. This is mostly in order to preserve backwards compatibility.
>
> ...
>
> Unfortunately, during DST transitions, some datetimes don’t exist or are ambiguous. In such situations, pendulum raises an exception. That’s why you should always create aware datetime objects when time zone support is enabled.

https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/docs/timezone.rst

Can you elaborate on your use case for using naive datetimes vs timezone aware datetimes?  I'd be happy to add more specific advice about that.

Comment: In my use case, the jobs I run are aligned with US stock market hours. For example, Nasdaq always opens at 9:30, and my jobs should always run at 9 am New York time regardless of DST. If I use UTC to schedule, I will have to update the schedule of every job whenever DST changes